How to use VBA to insert a photo IN a cell
I have an excel file that displays a sorted table.
The way I’m doing this is copying over rows that match the search criteria. However, Some of the cells contain pictures which makes this more annoying.
Currently the code works for photos that have been manually inserted INTO a cell. However, whenever I try to use VBA to replace placeholder text in a cell it just places the photo OVER the cell. Is there any way to mimic placing a photo IN a cell with VBA?


For M365

Sub InsertPicM365()
    Range("A1").InsertPictureInCell "C:\Pictures\image.png"
End Sub


For other version Excel

Sub InsertPic()
    Dim oShp As Object, iW As Double, iH As Double
    Const IMAGE = "C:\Pictures\image.png"
    Const CELL = "A1"
    ' insert image
    Set oShp = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(IMAGE)
    With Range(CELL)
        ' get the shrink/enlarge ratio
        iW = .Width / oShp.Width
        iH = .Height / oShp.Height
        ' shrink/enlarge image
        oShp.ShapeRange.ScaleWidth IIf(iW < iH, iW, iH), msoFalse, msoScaleFromTopLeft
        ' relocate image
        oShp.Top = .Top + (.Height - oShp.Height) / 2
        oShp.Left = .Left + (.Width - oShp.Width) / 2
    End With
End Sub

